# Twitter bootstrap - Responsive dropdown at top right

Tags: twitter, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a codeigniter application I'm templating with bootstrap
I have a main navbar

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">..........</div>
```

And want to put a responsive dropdown menu for the link located at top right

[image]

My main problem is that the dropdown works, but it generates a scroll when dropdown menu shows and it is not visible (at full width).

**I've used the button dropdowns... any other idea/suggestion? Thanks!**

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're just using the wrong component. What you should be using is this:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

That'll allow you to build the dropdown into the navigation rather than sticking a button in there. When your browser is narrower than a certain width with this approach, your menu slides down into a hierarchy.

Dropdown 3 gives you the HTML to float it right like you have in your screenshot:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
  <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" id="drop3" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown 3 <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Chords. Your dropdown looks great. It works awesome while window < 600px but the dropdown doesn't show while window is maximized. When clicked the dropdown, the container shows an scrollbar. Maybe z-index? Thanks again. Look: http://imgur.com/a/G6rcg/all

Comment: Update: it seems the problem was a sticky footer i've added, that modified .container-fluid's css, causing dropdown not to show. Will have to delete that sticky footer :(